# Parallax effect on android List/Grid view header doesn't resize well

Tags: android, mono, parallax

Im using @Vikram hack found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17932798/spotify-listview-header-image-effect) to mimic the parallax effect solemnly on the header, just like the new Airbnb and Spotify impementations.
The code is working fine on my test app, however on the main app where image size is set programmatically the effect seems to almost disappear, i.e. the image barely changes position/scrolls.

parallax_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cheesebaron.parallaxscrollview.ParallaxScrollView
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_canvas_parallax_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/parallax_headline"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="300dp"
      android:background="#ff00aa"
      android:scaleType="fitXY" />
  <cheesebaron.parallaxscrollview.ObservableLinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/observable_list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_content_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
      <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/parallax_list_holder"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
  </cheesebaron.parallaxscrollview.ObservableLinearLayout>
</cheesebaron.parallaxscrollview.ParallaxScrollView>
```

ObservableLinearLayout / AnotherView:

```
public class ObservableLinearLayout : LinearLayout
{
    protected ObservableLinearLayout(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
        : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }

    public ObservableLinearLayout(Context context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }

    public ObservableLinearLayout(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
        : base(context, attrs)
    {
    }

    private IScrollCallbacks mCallbacks;

    public interface IScrollCallbacks
    {
        void OnScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt);
    }

    public void SetCallbacks(IScrollCallbacks listener)
    {
        mCallbacks = listener;
    }


    //@Override
    public override void Draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.Draw(canvas);
    } 

    //@Override
    protected override void OnScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt)
    {
        base.OnScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        if (mCallbacks != null)
        {
            mCallbacks.OnScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        }
    }

    //@override
    protected override int ComputeVerticalScrollRange()
    {
        return base.ComputeVerticalScrollRange();
    }
}
```

ParallaxScrollView.cs:

```
public class ParallaxScrollView : ViewGroup
{
    private const GravityFlags DefaultChildGravity = GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal;
    private new const string Tag = "ParallaxScrollView";
    //private const float DefaultParallaxOffset = 0.2f;
    private const float DefaultParallaxOffset = 0.5f;

    private float _parallaxOffset = DefaultParallaxOffset;
    private View _background;
    private ObservableScrollView _scrollView;

    private int _backgroundRight;
    private int _backgroundBottom;

    private int _scrollContentHeight;
    private int _scrollViewHeight;

    private float _scrollDiff;

    public float ParallaxOffset
    {
        get { return _parallaxOffset; }
        set
        {
            var offset = (float)Math.Round(value * 100) / 100;
            _parallaxOffset = offset > 0.0 ? offset : DefaultParallaxOffset;

            RequestLayout();
        }
    }

    public ParallaxScrollView(Context context)
        : this(context, null)
    { }

    public ParallaxScrollView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
        : this(context, attrs, 0)
    { }

    public ParallaxScrollView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
        : base(context, attrs, defStyle)
    {
        var a = Context.Theme.ObtainStyledAttributes(attrs, Resource.Styleable.parallaxscrollview, 0, 0);

        try
        {
            ParallaxOffset = a.GetFloat(Resource.Styleable.parallaxscrollview_parallaxOffset,
                                        DefaultParallaxOffset);
        }
        finally
        {
            a.Recycle();
        }

    }

    public override void AddView(View child)
    {
        if (ChildCount > 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("ParallaxScrollView can only host two direct children");
        base.AddView(child);
    }

    public override void AddView(View child, int index)
    {
        if (ChildCount > 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("ParallaxScrollView can only host two direct children");
        base.AddView(child, index);
    }

    public override void AddView(View child, int index, LayoutParams @params)
    {
        if (ChildCount > 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("ParallaxScrollView can only host two direct children");
        base.AddView(child, index, @params);
    }

    public override void AddView(View child, int width, int height)
    {
        if (ChildCount > 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("ParallaxScrollView can only host two direct children");
        base.AddView(child, width, height);
    }

    public override void AddView(View child, LayoutParams @params)
    {
        if (ChildCount > 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("ParallaxScrollView can only host two direct children");
        base.AddView(child, @params);
    }

    protected override void OnFinishInflate()
    {
        base.OnFinishInflate();

        if (ChildCount > 2)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("ParallaxScrollView can only host two direct children");

        OrganiseViews();
    }

    protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        if (_scrollView != null)
        {
            MeasureChild(_scrollView, MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(
                MeasureSpec.GetSize(widthMeasureSpec), MeasureSpecMode.AtMost),
                MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(MeasureSpec.GetSize(heightMeasureSpec),
                MeasureSpecMode.AtMost));

            _scrollContentHeight = _scrollView.GetChildAt(0).MeasuredHeight;
            _scrollViewHeight = _scrollView.MeasuredHeight;
        }
        if (_background != null)
        {
            var minHeight = (int)(_scrollViewHeight + _parallaxOffset
                               * (_scrollContentHeight - _scrollViewHeight));
            minHeight = Math.Max(minHeight, MeasureSpec.GetSize(heightMeasureSpec));

            MeasureChild(_background, MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(
                MeasureSpec.GetSize(widthMeasureSpec), MeasureSpecMode.Exactly),
                MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(minHeight, MeasureSpecMode.Exactly));

            _backgroundRight = Left + _background.MeasuredWidth;
            _backgroundBottom = Top + _background.MeasuredHeight;

            _scrollDiff = (_background.MeasuredHeight - _scrollViewHeight)
                          / (float)(_scrollContentHeight - _scrollViewHeight);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        var parentLeft = PaddingLeft;
        var parentRight = r - l - PaddingRight;
        var parentTop = PaddingTop;
        var parentBottom = b - t - PaddingBottom;

        if (_scrollView != null && _scrollView.Visibility != ViewStates.Gone)
        {
            var lp = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)_scrollView.LayoutParameters;
            var width = _scrollView.MeasuredWidth;
            var height = _scrollView.MeasuredHeight;

            int childLeft;
            int childTop;

            var gravity = lp.Gravity;
            if (gravity == GravityFlags.NoGravity)
                gravity = DefaultChildGravity;

            var horizontalGravity = gravity & GravityFlags.HorizontalGravityMask;
            var verticalGravity = gravity & GravityFlags.VerticalGravityMask;

            switch (horizontalGravity)
            {
                case GravityFlags.Left:
                    childLeft = parentLeft - lp.LeftMargin;
                    break;
                case GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal:
                    childLeft = parentLeft + (parentRight - parentLeft - width) / 2 + lp.LeftMargin - lp.RightMargin;
                    break;
                case GravityFlags.Right:
                    childLeft = parentRight - width - lp.RightMargin;
                    break;
                default:
                    childLeft = parentLeft + lp.LeftMargin;
                    break;
            }

            switch (verticalGravity)
            {
                case GravityFlags.Top:
                    childTop = parentTop + lp.TopMargin;
                    break;
                case GravityFlags.CenterVertical:
                    childTop = parentTop + (parentBottom - parentTop - height) / 2 + lp.TopMargin - lp.BottomMargin;
                    break;
                case GravityFlags.Bottom:
                    childTop = parentBottom - height - lp.BottomMargin;
                    break;
                default:
                    childTop = parentTop + lp.TopMargin;
                    break;
            }

            _scrollView.Layout(childLeft, childTop, childLeft + width, childTop + height);
        }

        if (_background != null && _scrollView != null)
        {
            //var scrollYCenterOffset = -_scrollView.ScrollY;
            var scrollYCenterOffset = _scrollView.ScrollY;
            //changes the velocity of the effect
            var offset = (int)((scrollYCenterOffset * _scrollDiff) / 2);
            _background.Layout(Left, offset, _backgroundRight, offset + _backgroundBottom);
        }
    }

    public override LayoutParams GenerateLayoutParams(IAttributeSet attrs)
    {
        return new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(Context, attrs);
    }

    protected override LayoutParams GenerateLayoutParams(LayoutParams p)
    {
        return new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(p);
    }

    protected override LayoutParams GenerateDefaultLayoutParams()
    {
        return new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MatchParent, LayoutParams.MatchParent,
                                            GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal);
    }

    protected override bool CheckLayoutParams(LayoutParams p)
    {
        return p is FrameLayout.LayoutParams;
    }

    private void OrganiseViews()
    {
        if (ChildCount <= 0) return;

        if (ChildCount == 1)
        {
            var foreground = GetChildAt(0);
            OrganiseBackgroundView(null);
            OrganiseForegroundView(foreground);
        }
        else if (ChildCount == 2)
        {
            var background = GetChildAt(0);
            var foreground = GetChildAt(1);

            OrganiseBackgroundView(background);
            OrganiseForegroundView(foreground);
        }
        else
            throw new InvalidOperationException("ParallaxScrollView can host only two direct children");
    }

    private void OrganiseBackgroundView(View background)
    {
        _background = background;
    }

    private void OrganiseForegroundView(View foreground)
    {
        var insertPos = ChildCount - 1;

        if (foreground is ObservableScrollView)
        {
            _scrollView = (ObservableScrollView)foreground;
            _scrollView.ScrollChanged -= ScrollViewOnScrollChanged;
        }
        else if (foreground is ViewGroup && !(foreground is ScrollView))
        {
            _scrollView = new ObservableScrollView(Context, null);
            RemoveView(foreground);
            _scrollView.AddView(foreground);
            AddView(_scrollView, insertPos);
        }
        else if (foreground is ScrollView)
        {
            var child = ((ScrollView)foreground).ChildCount > 0 ?
                ((ScrollView)foreground).GetChildAt(0) : null;

            _scrollView = new ObservableScrollView(Context, null);
            RemoveView(foreground);
            if (child != null)
                _scrollView.AddView(child);
            AddView(_scrollView, insertPos);
        }
        else
        {
            _scrollView = new ObservableScrollView(Context, null);
            RemoveView(foreground);
            _scrollView.AddView(foreground);
            AddView(_scrollView, insertPos);
        }

        if (_scrollView != null)
        {
            _scrollView.LayoutParameters = foreground.LayoutParameters;
            _scrollView.ScrollChanged += ScrollViewOnScrollChanged;
            _scrollView.FillViewport = true;
        }
    }

    private void ScrollViewOnScrollChanged(object sender, ObservableScrollViewEventArgs args)
    {
        RequestLayout();
    }
}
}
```

the calling func:

```
private void BuildMobileListView()
{
    var listContainer = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.parallax_list_holder);
    var listMainHolder = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.list_content_container);
    var listView = new MvxListView(listContainer.Context, null, new MainCanvasListAdapter(this, (IMvxAndroidBindingContext) BindingContext))
    {
        VerticalFadingEdgeEnabled = false,
        //the first item is the headline you get it separately
        ItemsSource = ViewModel.Items.GetRange(1, ViewModel.Items.Count-1),
        LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent),
        CacheColorHint = Color.Transparent,
    };

    listView.VerticalFadingEdgeEnabled = false;
    listView.Divider = null;
    listContainer.AddView(listView);
    listView.Post(() =>
    {
        SetScrollableViewHeight(listView, listContainer);
        var p = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)listMainHolder.LayoutParameters;
        listMainHolder.LayoutParameters = p;
    });
}
```

the post function:

```
public void SetScrollableViewHeight(GridView gridView, LinearLayout llMain)
        {
            var gridViewAdapter = gridView.Adapter;
            if (gridViewAdapter == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var totalHeight = 0;
            var firstHeight = 0;
            var desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(
                                 gridView.Width, MeasureSpecMode.AtMost);

            for (int i = 0; i < gridViewAdapter.Count; i++)
            {

                if (i == 0)
                {
                    View listItem = gridViewAdapter.GetView(i, null, gridView);
                    listItem.Measure(desiredWidth, (int)MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified);
                    firstHeight = listItem.MeasuredHeight + DroidAttributes.MOBILLE_GRID_VIEW_MARGIN*2;
                }
                totalHeight += firstHeight;
            }
            totalHeight = totalHeight / 2;

            var lParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)llMain.LayoutParameters;

            lParams.Height = totalHeight /*+ DroidAttributes.MOBILLE_GRID_VIEW_MARGIN * 2*//*+ (gridView.ListPaddingBottom * (gridViewAdapter.Count - 1)/2)*/;
            llMain.LayoutParameters = lParams;
            _mobileLayoutContainer.RequestLayout();
        }
```

the margin set on the @+id/list_content_container is set programmatically according to the headline image's width/height.

Ive been using almost the same code on a different project and got much better "parallax" results, can anyone point me to what